# Deploying postgresql with bash - Syntax Error

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, shell, debian

This is my deployment snippet:

```
APP="test"
DBPASS=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
sudo -u postgres -H createuser --no-createrole --no-superuser --no-createdb $APP_main
sudo -u postgres -H createdb -O $APP_main $APP_main
sudo -u postgres -H psql -c "alter user $APP_main with password '$DBPASS'"
```

This is my log out:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/createdb: option requires an argument -- 'O'                              
Try "createdb --help" for more information.                                                           
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "with password"                                                       
LINE 1: alter user  with password 'hCGCly4ZVfu42Dr956ncypuf6mt0lBiY'
```

Can anyone explain what is going wrong? I have specified the O argument it just doesn't seem to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
$APP_main
```

You perhaps wanted to append `_main` to the variable `$APP`.  Instead say:

```
${APP}_main
```

This would expand the variable `$APP` and append `_main` to it.

Comment: @Rob3 That's a purely database question.  I'd say that you ask that in a different thread!